# Brasero Disc Burner - Vers 3.12.1 - Do Not Burn In Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: iso, dvd, burning

I have never had any issues with **Brasero** before until now!
Ever since i upgraded from **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS** to **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS**
Brasero have kept failing to burn everything.

One of two things happen everytime i try to burn something:

- **4.37GB DVD** disc (It claim the disc is too small to burn content at **700MB**)
- It starts burning, get stuck or loads really really slow and stays there for hours then it fail and crashes and says an error have accured

***ERROR Message:***

[image: Brasero Disc Burner - Vers 3.12.1]

Comment: Can you add also details displayed in "Show details" in "Sorry, Ubuntu 16.04 has experienced an internal error"? It may require scrolling down.

Comment: Without that it is hard to say more than "Brasero works for me on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS".